# Where I can find PHP plugin for an existing Eclipse IDE Helios SR2 for JavaScript Web Developers

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use eclipse IDE (Helios SR2 for JavaScript Web Developers) for js, gae, html, css etc. development. And want to use the same for php development as well. Unfortunately, I am not able to find any reliable link online for php plugin that I can add to my existing eclipse IDE. Any that I find require another complete eclipse-for-php IDE.

Will greatly appreciate help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Have you resolved this ?

Comment: @muhammad-gelbana Nopes!

Answer (score 0):

install pdt plugin, follow the instructions at link
http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I found that link earlier and installed complete package (which of course is a separate eclipse). This time I downloaded http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/release but get the following error: 
Missing requirement: PDT Core Plug-in 3.1.2.201212211235 (org.eclipse.php.debug.core 3.1.2.201212211235) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.dltk.core. Any further help will be appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As said above in the other answer, you need to download 'pdt' plugin.
Regarding the error when trying to install the pdt plugin: you need to install the Dynamic Language Toolkit before the pdt plugin. Refer to this question for further information:
[Eclipse PDT plugin installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087492/eclipse-pdt-plugin-installation)