# Eclipse PDT plugin installation

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I'm trying to install PDT plugin in Eclipse and I get error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: PHP Development Tools (PDT) 3.1.2.201212211235 (org.eclipse.php.feature.group 3.1.2.201212211235)
  Missing requirement: PDT Debug UI Plug-in 3.1.2.201212211235 (org.eclipse.php.debug.ui 3.1.2.201212211235) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.dltk.debug.ui [4.0.0,5.0.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: PHP Development Tools (PDT) 3.1.2.201212211235 (org.eclipse.php.feature.group 3.1.2.201212211235)
    To: org.eclipse.php.debug.ui [3.1.2.201212211235]
```

Answer (score 14):

dgolovins answer worked for me.

First install Dynamic Language Toolkit:
Help-->Install New Software --> Add --> Location: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/4.0-stable/

Then install PDT:
Help-->Install New Software --> Add --> Location: http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/latest

Answer (score 3):

This message is awful and means that org.eclipse.dltk.debug.ui with 4.0.0 <= version <5.0.0 is not available in your eclipse installation or form available eclipse update sites in Install dialog.

Add [Eclipse Dynamic Language Toolkit update site](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates-dev/4.0-stable/) in eclipse Install dialog and then try to install PDT again.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04 the solution presented by @Manfred did not solve my installation problem.

Then I followed the solution presented in [PHPeclipse](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PHPEclipse)

> Enabling PHP Support
>
> As-standard, Eclipse does not come with support for PHP. This must be
>   added, and added as root.
>
> ```
> Launch Eclipse as root from the command line:
>
>     $ sudo eclipse (gksudo causes an unusual warning). 
>
> When the "Welcome to Eclipse" screen is displayed, select Help->Install New Software...
>
> The "Galileo" site must be added, click "Add..." and input:
>
>     Name: Galileo Location: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo/ 
>
> Once this is available, select "Galileo" in the Work with: drop-down list.
>
> Enter "php" into the filter text, two entries should be displayed for "PHP Developer Tools (PDT)"; one under Programming Languages,
> ```
>
> another under Web, XML, and Java EE Development. Select both and click
>   "Next >".
>
> ```
> Verify that the items you wish to install are displayed on the "Install Details" screen and click "Finish".
> Eclipse will need restarted for the update to complete.
> ```
>
> With this complete, you should be able to launch Eclipse under a
>   normal user account and select New->Project...->PHP->PHP Project.